# jQuery - hover pop-up until mouse out

Tags: jquery

I am working on this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iqagov/11/edit) and everything works okay except I want to make this pop-up menu (appears after 1 sec from hovering) stay in until `mouseout` so user(s) can hover on the list.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please post the smallest amount of code that still shows the problem, both here and in a fiddle or bin.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand yes, I understand that. I should have isolated the problem area only. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I would recommend using a plugin, it will make this much easier and has a lot of options.  I have used http://qtip2.com/ in the past with a lot of success.

Comment: You need to add the same hover on the list too so that it stays when you hover on it. Rightnow, you have hover on only input so when mouse exits that area, the list disappears

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var $popup = $('.popup');

    $popup.hover(function() {
        clearTimeout($popup.data('outTimeout'))
    }, function() {
        $(this).finish().fadeOut();
    })

    $('.input-block-level').hover(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('id');
        clearTimeout($popup.data('outTimeout'))
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $popup.fadeIn().insertAfter('#' + target);
        }, 1000);
        $popup.data('inTimeout', timeout)
    }, function() {
        clearTimeout($popup.data('inTimeout'))
        var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $popup.stop(true).fadeOut();
        }, 300);
        $popup.data('outTimeout', timeout)
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Demo: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/izuqax/1/edit)

Comment: It works like a charm! By the way, Where do 'inTimeout' and 'outTimeout' come from? I just want to know. Thanks!

Comment: @SeongLee I'm storing the reference to the `setTimout()` calls as those data attributes so that I can reference them later

Comment: Thanks. It's just that the variable is declared as `timeout` but what is being used has `out` and `in` prepended so wondered how would this reference without an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`$("Id").hover(function(){$("#popId").fadeOut(1000);$("#popId").fadeIn(500);});`

Comment: I am not sure about this approach as it only forces it to stay in for pre-defined interval...I want it to stay as long as mouse is hovered over. Thanks for your input though!